# Space between flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to learn flex box but my knowledge isn't good enough for me to know what to search on Google or Stack.

I want the first element, **'stock'** to be left aligned to the flex container and the **last** social media icon to be right aligned.

I need space between the stock list and the first social media icon, and then a little bit of space between each social icon.

[image: image example]

```css
.flex-container {
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 }
 
 #flex-items {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 background-color: orange;
 }
 
 .stock {
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #6dc993;
 display: flex;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 flex-grow: 1;
 }
 
 .stock > p {
 margin-left: 5%;
 display: flex;
 align-self: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 height: 20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div id="flex-items">
<div class="stock"><p>Stock List</p></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for your problem

```
.stock {
   margin-right: auto;
   background-color: #6dc993;
   display: flex;
   border-right: 5px solid blue;
   flex-grow: 1; //removed
   flex-basis: 30%; //added
 }
```

I have added the `flex-basis` to a static 30% and removed the dynamic `flex-grow`. Since the `flex-grow` is set to `1` in your case the width of your `.stock` will increase relative to the width of the screen.

Finally added spacing for the social icons.

```
#flex-items div:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/hp36mr8w/)**

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of `flex-grow` on .stock because that letting it grow to fit the rest of the space which is exactly what you don't want, then target the social media divs and add margin to space them out. (Or you can add another container around the icons and flex those out space between). And then I add a width to the stock, 40% as example. Can make this width as flex-basis as others are saying.

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#flex-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: orange;
}

.stock {
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #6dc993;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.stock>p {
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 20%;
}

#flex-items div:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex-items">
    <div class="stock">
      <p>Stock List</p>
    </div>
    <div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
    <div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
    <div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
    <div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
    <div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, would just removing flex-grow and adding flex-items > div:nth-child(n+2) { padding-left: 10px; } also work?

Comment: Yea the selector seems right for all items after the first. I would personally use margin for spacing. If those are links padding will just make the link include empty space

Comment: Or you can add a class to all of those divs to select them easier like others have suggested

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```css
.flex-container {
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 }
 
 #flex-items {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background-color: orange;
   height: 75px;
 }
 
 .stock {
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #6dc993;
 display: flex;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 flex-grow: 1;
 width: 33%;
 }
.links {
  width: 66%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.links > div > img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

 
 .stock > p {
 margin-left: 5%;
 display: flex;
 align-self: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 height: 20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div id="flex-items">
<div class="stock"><p>Stock List</p></div>
<div class="links">
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
<div><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mentioned the issue is with your flex-grow, and i wouldn't suggest to remove that attribute but instead to understand better about flexbox, please refer to this [Flex-grow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-grow). Adding flex grow will resize all the div items.

> The flex-grow property specifies how much a flex item will grow relative to the rest of the flex items.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jidelambo/pen/jxpmbJ)

```css
.flex-container {
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 }
 
 #flex-items {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 background-color: orange;
 }
.socialWrapper {
  display: flex;
}
 
 .stock {
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #6dc993;
 display: flex;
 width: 40%;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 }
 
 .stock > p {
 margin-left: 5%;
 display: flex;
 align-self: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 height: 20%;
 }

.icon-wrap {
  margin-left:5px;
}
.icon-wrap img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex-items">
    <div class="stock"><p>Stock List</p></div>
    <div class="socialWrapper">
      <div class="icon-wrap"><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
      <div class="icon-wrap"><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
      <div class="icon-wrap"><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
      <div class="icon-wrap"><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
      <div class="icon-wrap"><img title="Like us on Facebook" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/ULYeTe.jpg" alt="Like us on Facebook" width="68" height="76" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```